# How to pull out corresponding column and row figures from a two dimensional data table?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

peeps.

I currently have a two dimensional data table, which measures the sensitivity of two inputs, with regards to profit.

The whole data table, is (`D183:AI234`). I take the max profit one can gain from taking a `max()` value, and I was wondering what formula could I create, so I can get the corresponding values in the data table (two of them) which create the profit judged by `max()` from the whole data table.

Things I've tried: `hlookup`, `vlookup` to get both the inputs from row and column, but get N/A from both.

For example, to get the input from the row, based on `look_up` value, I used this formula: `=HLOOKUP(E237,D183:AI234,1,0)`

Kind Regards

Data Table:

[image: data table]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousands worth [mcve]

Comment: Surprisingly I'm not sure there's a one-liner excel function for this.  If you want to stay out of VBA you can just add a `match` for the maximum value at the end of each row and column, but that seems pretty convoluted.  There should be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hacky way to do it using array functions. I assume there is something cleaner.

**Edit** I misread the original question.

I am assuming that the data itself is in the range D183:AI234--the labels for the y-category are in C183:C234 and the labels for the x-category are in D182:AI182.

To find the row of the maximum value: `MAX((D183:AI234 = MaxVal)*ROW(D183:D234))`

With the row number there are a variety of options for actually accessing the value in your y-labels:

1. You can `OFFSET` from the upper left of the table (assumed to be
   C182).  `OFFSET(C182, MAX((D183:AI234 = MaxVal)*ROW(D183:D234)) - ROW(C182), 0)`.
2. You can access the labeled cell using `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS`, the row number, and a column identifier for the labels. `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX((D183:AI234 = MaxVal)*ROW(D183:D234)), COLUMN(C182)))`
3. You can determine the relative position among the labels and use `INDEX` and the row number to retrieve the value.  `INDEX(C183:C234,MAX((D183:AI234 = MaxVal)*ROW(D183:D234)), COLUMN(C182)) - ROW(C182))`

Note that these are all array functions and must be entered with `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`.

I'd prefer the `INDEX` approach as it is non-volatile (both `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are volatile functions and will recalculate every time a change is made to the sheet/excel recalculates) and I generally consider it to be better practice.

To get the x-value you identify the column of the maximum with `MAX((D183:AI234 = MaxVal)*COLUMN(D183:AI183))` and adapt whichever of the three methods you choose.

**Original answer** to find the *address* of the max (but not the associated category values) below:

To find the row of the maximum entry you want to multiply a boolean array where your values match the maximum, so, that is `(D183:AI234 = MaxVal)` by the row numbers, so `ROW(D183:D234)`.  The result of that multiplication is a vector of (0,0,..,Row of Maximum Val,...), so you take the `MAX` of that to find the row number.

The same is true for the column, but you would use `COLUMN(D183:AI183)`.  Then you can get a cell address using the `ADDRESS` function.

Putting it all together...

`=ADDRESS(MAX((D183:AI234 = MaxVal)*ROW(D183:D234)),MAX((D183:AI234 = MaxVal)*COLUMN(D183:AI183)))`

This must be entered as an array function (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER)

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting a potential solution. I get a "The formula you typed contains an error for both" is there a way to get around this. Regards

Comment: Did you swap in the actual address in your worksheet for "MaxVal"?  And are you entering it as an array function?

Comment: I entered the formulas as they are in a cell, I guess that's wrong.,,

Comment: You don't enter the `{}` - Excel will add that for you when you use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: This gives the address of the max value.  OP wants the X and Y values corresponding to that max, I think.  You could use your technique with an Index into the X row and (separately) the Y column to get the required values

Comment: =VLOOKUP(E237,D183:AI234,1,1) This worked for the figures on the left column, however I cant seem to get the figures on the top row (the %s) which is also a critical figure

Comment: @chrisneilsen -- wow good catch, I completely misread it on the first pass.  updated accordingly.